# Set action="" with a crispy form

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I am enjoying crispy forms but unfortunately I don't know how to force this module to render a `<form ... action="">` html tag.

The usecase is in a create view and would be the same in ant edit view. In those views, you want the html form to POST in the same page to perform validation, right? ([see docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.8/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview))

My form is:

```
class InvitedPersonModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = InvitedPerson
        fields = ['email',]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(InvitedPersonModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_id = 'id-invitedpersonForm'
        self.helper.form_class = 'blueForms'
        self.helper.form_method = 'POST'
        self.helper.form_action = ''
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', _('Invite')))
```

This will render a form with no action at all.
This : `self.helper.form_action = ''` will render an `action=""""`.

And I cannot perform a request.get_full_path() as request is not passed to the ModelForm.

What is you advise?

Here is my html code, this is not performing any POST request on button pressed:

```
<form id="id-invitedpersonForm" class="blueForms" method="post">

    <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='CqcoQFZDSvniyqOXMkdCqHQcDtm8tQMU'/>

    <div id="div_id_email" class="form-group">
        <label for="id_email" class="control-label  requiredField">
            Email<span class="asteriskField">*</span>
        </label>

        <div class="controls ">
            <input class="emailinput form-control" id="id_email" maxlength="254" name="email"
                   type="email"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="controls ">
            <input type="submit"
                   name="submit"
                   value="Invite"

                   class="btn btn-primary"
                   id="submit-id-submit"
                    />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: If the form has no action, won't it be submitted to the current url (which is what you want)?

Comment: There is absolutely no difference between no action and `action=""`.

Comment: Yes, a <form> without action should be submitted to his url, but this is not happening in my case, I really don't know why.

Comment: I have found a hacked solution: action="?". It works ok, but I'm not very happy since I don't understand why my no-action form is not ok.